# How to improve the Update operation performance in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

We are trying to update the 20000 records in single commit which is taking more than 30 minutes. We are thinking to reduce the records counts and implementing the batch process which will commit the 1000 records. Can any provide the suggestion to improve the performance?

Comment: What is your code? I think the original Ef 6 does not support batch insert or update. They have extensions to do batch updates.

Comment: @isaeid , we have 'for each' loop for update the records. we will set the count for maximum records to be updated.

Comment: Actually they do not. There ARE extensions, but THEY do not have the - they are third party.

Comment: if i disable the 'AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;' option , will it help me ? @TomTom

Comment: It will make internal processing faster. It will not avoid the "one insert per item, separate from all others, with full waiting for the return". WRONG TOOL. EF6 never was made for bulk inserts - using it for those is like trying to cook a mean with ONLY a knife. Specialized tool != "use it for everything".

Comment: For this task, EF is slow. I resolved a similar problem buy simply using SQL. if you do this, refresh your dbContext afterwards as it will be "invalidated" by the SQL changing the data.

Answer (score 1):

By default, EF does 1 query for single update. You can write stored procedure accepting table valued parameter, thus updating multiple rows with single query, reducing roundtrip overhead.
Also for bulk inserts you can use `SqlBulkCopy` class.

**Update**: alternatively you can use 3rd party libraries to do this. Something like https://entityframework-plus.net/?z=ef-extended and https://entityframework-extensions.net/ I also used [simple wrapper](https://github.com/ronnieoverby/RonnieOverbyGrabBag/blob/master/BulkInserter.cs) over SqlBulkCopy for bulk inserts.

**Update2**: Example from Microsoft how to use Table Valued Parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters  That is for ADO.Net, but similar approach is possible with EF.

Comment: We cannot use the third party libraries

Comment: Then you should go route with writing stored procedure to update all values at once. That procedure will accept multiple rows at single table-valued parameter and do bulk update code in T-SQL

Comment: @vanapandiNarayanan Updated with link to Microsoft example

Answer (score 0):

You can use stored procedures or use Ef extensions, for example please see https://entityframework-plus.net/batch-update .

Comment: One of the worst use cases for SP's ever, me thinks.